# How to cache with weak references when values refer back to keys?

Tags: java, caching, guava, weak-references

I'm using Guava's `Cache<Key, Value>`. Whenever `Key` is no more strongly reachable, the cache entry should be garbage collected (someday...). Using `CacheBuilder.weakKeys()` would do exactly that, if there weren't a reference from `Value` back to `Key`.

I could make this reference weak, but this could anytime make my `Value` quite invalid. I could handle it, but I'd prefer not to.

I could use `weakValues()`, but this could lead to very early evictions, as my values are only referenced for a short time.

Maybe I could use `softValues()`, but `SoftReference`s are [quite broken](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=cfd518f51afc7780e5188276b5f9?bug_id=6912889).

Probably I'm getting something wrongly.... what is the right solution?

#### Update

What I need could be achieved simply by putting a reference to `Value` into each `Key`, but this is not possible as `Key` is not under my control. If it was, then I'd need no cache, no weak references, nothing.

This way, each `Key` would keep its corresponding `Value` reachable, which is fine<sup>1</sup>. Also each  `Value` would keep its `Key` reachable, but this is no problem as there're no long existing references to `Value`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Some expiration would be better but it's not necessary.

Comment: If you have control over value, make the `Key key`, `WeakReference<Key>` key. If I have control over the keys and need such functionality, I tend to end up w/ a final field into the key `weakThis` to conserve the amount of WeakReferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is unsolvable without [ephemerons](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/270000/263733/p176-hayes.pdf?ip=216.239.45.4&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&CFID=96142969&CFTOKEN=46796959&__acm__=1342478362_8336a73eab1a1136cb76b54c06e5c2bc).

Comment: Your link is dead, [this one works](http://swiki-lifia.info.unlp.edu.ar/ContextAware/uploads/29/Ephemerons%20-%20A%20New%20Finalization%20Mechanism.pdf).

Comment: After having read the paper I see you're right. I ran exactly into the problem desribed under "property table", which needs the ephemerons. In case somebody cares: I found a very simple definition of ephemerons: It's a key value pair where the value field is reachable iff both the ephemeron and its key are reachable.

Comment: Would there be any nice way to have a e.g. a `WeakHashMap<string,string>` which, given a reference to a string that matches one in the collection, would return the one in the collection, but which would drop strings to which no references existed outside the collection?  Having each value be a `WeakReference` might be possible, but seems somewhat icky, since the collection is already holding a `WeakReference` which is just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer from Value -> Key doesn't matter as long as nothing else is holding on to Value.

When the Cache dumps Key, it will be collected.

If you have System->Cache->Key<-Value, when Cache drops key you get System->Cache Key<-Value. The link from Key back up to System (the memory root for this example) is broken, and Key will be recovered.

Comment: I don't think it ever happens. There's a chain `System->Cache->Value->Key` which persists until the entry gets evicted, i.e., forever when only `weakKeys()` gets used.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want weakKeys, then having a weak reference from the value to the key is the right thing to do.

If that doesn't feel right to you, then please provide more info about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually, the reason why I can't let `Value` reference `Key` is more complicated than I thought. I'm not going into this now, but I've added some explation of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it might be possible to create a copy of key, and use that as the key in the map?  I am thinking you might have something like

```
Value v = SomeLibrary.giveMeSomething();
String k = v.getName();
String k1 = new String(k);
cache.put(k1,v);
```

This will work b/c k.equals(k1) and k != k1.  Hopefully you can create a copy or clone of the type used for Key (which probably isn't String in your case).

**However**, this changes the lifecycle of the key -- since it is no longer the one in Value.  If you have control over the lifecycle of the particular object you've put in the map, then you're OK.

Do you think that might work?

Comment: Not in my case... the problem are the references to the (original) key in the value which keep the key reachable. Look at the accepted answer in case you're interested.