# How to simulate a direct reference from one Java object to another?

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, weak-references

Say I have 2 Java classes, A and B that look like this:

```
public static class A {
}

public static class B {
    private A parent;

    public B(A parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Now, I have an instance of class A (call it 'xa') and an instance of class B ('yb').  I would like a general way to prevent 'yb' from being garbage collected until 'xa' is eligible for GC. Assume I cannot modify the code for either class. Basically, I want to achieve the exact same behavior that would occur if 'xa' had a direct reference to 'yb' (via a field).

I've explored trying to use PhantomReferences + ReferenceQueues, but I always seem to run into a dead end where 'yb's direct reference to 'xa' ends up preventing both objects from being GC'd...

FYI, my actual use-case is a weak listener that only needs to exist for as long as another object does.

Comment: Could you explain your use case in more detail?  This still seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I'm afraid, you're asking exactly what [I did here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11445822/581205) and the answer is "impossible".

Comment: Ah, indeed, that is an exact parallel to my problem. I suspected it may simply not be possible in Java; maybe Java will get [Ephemerons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron) someday...